# Downloads using wget or curl are slower than Safari

Tags: macos, curl, wget

My program is trying to download a 90 MB file from a file server. The SSH is timing out on 60 seconds. I found out that Safari browser downloads the file in less than 15 seconds but curl or wget take little more than 60 seconds. Why is that happening?

I'm using Mac Mini running Sierra and connected through an IPv4 address.